# Question about $G_\delta$ set

Tags: general-topology, self-learning

I'm on summer break but I want to keep my math skills sharp so I'm self-studying a bit from Munkres.

This question is from pg 194, chapter 4 about the Countability and Separation Axioms. 
I've already seen this:
[why is one point set in a first countable $T_1$ space a $G_\delta$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/536431/why-is-one-point-set-in-a-first-countable-t-1-space-a-g-delta), but was wondering if my solution is also valid.

$a.$ A $G_\delta$ set in a space $X$ is a set $A$ that equals a countable intersection of open sets of $X$. Show that in a first-countable $T_1$ space, every one-point set is a $G_\delta$ set.

$b.$ There is a familiar space in which every one-point set is a $G_\delta$ set, which nevertheless does not satisfy the first countability axiom. What is it?

Here's my attempted solution for $a.$ and I'm wondering if it's correct.

$a.$ Let $\{x\}$ be a one-point set in $X$. Since $X$ is first countable there is a countable basis of $x$. Denote this by $\mathscr{B}$.

WTS: $\cap_{n\in N}B_n$ = $\{x\}$.

$\subset )$ $x\in\cap_{n\in N}B_n$ since each $B_n$ is a neighborhood of $x$.

$\supset )$ Let $y \in \cap_{n\in N}B_n$. Then we have two cases.

Case 1: $y=x$ then we are done.

Case 2: $y\neq x$. Then $y$ is a limit point of $\{x\}$ since $y \in \cap_{n\in N}B_n$ and each $B_n$ contains $x$. Therefore $y \in \overline{\{x\}}$ but $\{x\}$ is closed since $X$ is $T_1$, so  $\overline{\{x\}} =\{x\}$, thus $y=x$.

Therefore every one-point set in a first-countable $T_1$ space is a $G_\delta$ set.

b. I'm quite unsure about $b.$ since it has to be a non-metric space. Any hints here would be great.

Comment: For part a), I would suggest you use the $T_1$ property in the form that for $y\neq x$ there is an open $U$ containing $x$ but not $y$. (At least) One of the $B_n$ is contained in $U$, therefore $y \notin \bigcap B_n$.

Comment: Okay yes this makes much more sense thanks.

Comment: For $b$, can you think of a quotient space formed by collapsing a subset $A$ of some metric space $X$ to a point, where only one point doesn't have a countable local base? That would rule out all the other points in $X/A$ as non-$G_\delta$ sets (as this quotient space is Hausdorff).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you just wrote, I want all one-point sets to be $G_\delta$ not non-$G_\delta$.

Comment: The verb *rule out sth as [something]* means that it is **not** [something], if I looked it up correctly. So your points are not non-$G_\delta$ ;-)

Comment: Oh yes you're right sorry, that's just a round-about way of saying it I guess. I'll think over your comment thanks.

Comment: Maybe not the best way of saying it, but I wanted to practice my English ;-) Don't forget to put `@Stefan` in your comment.

Comment: @StefanHamcke Could you provide a more detailed hint? I'm not very comfortable with the quotient topology as I haven't worked with it very much. I've shown that a retraction is a quotient map and a couple of other problems in Munkres but not much else.

Comment: The space I mean is $\Bbb R/\Bbb Z$, the real line with the integers collapsed to a point. It is an infinite wedge of circles, and each point except $\Bbb Z$ has a countable local base.

Comment: For *b* you can use any countable T$_1$-space which is not first countable; e.g., $\mathbb N$ topologized so that a set $S\subseteq\mathbb N$ is open if either $1\notin S$ or else $$\sum_{n\in\mathbb N\setminus S}\frac1n\lt\infty.$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your idea for a) is essentially OK: we take a countable local base $B_n$, $n \in N$ at $x$, and prove that $\cap_n B_n = \{x\}$. Indeed, clearly $x$ is in this intersection, as all $B_n$ must contain $x$. And if $y \neq x$, by $T_1$-ness, there is an open subset $O$ that contains $x$ but not $y$, so there is some $B_k$ with $x \in B_k \subset O$, so $B_k$ also does not contain $y$, and certainly $\cap B_n$ then does not. This shows that no other point than $x$ can be in $\cap B_n$.

For a familiar example I would pick $R^\omega$ in the box topology. If $x = (x_0, x_1,\ldots)$ is a point in it, the open sets $U_n = (x_0 - \frac{1}{n}, x_0 + \frac{1}{n}) \times (x_1 - \frac{1}{n}, x_1 + \frac{1}{n}) \times \ldots$ have the property that $\cap_n U_n = \{x\}$. But you can show that it is not first countable at any point (assume we have a countable local base at $x$, assume we have box-open basic sets as a local base WLOG, and then find a basic open set around $x$ that cannot contain any of them...).

Stefan's example of $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ will also do fine (it's less extreme, as it is first countable except at one point).